# Change language of keyboard in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm completely new to Ubuntu, so I need some help figuring out how to change the system settings.

I want to change language from English to Portuguese. I've read that I can do this in the Setup Menu, but I can't find this menu or setting.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: at top of your screen is a status bar look near its right side for a widget saying  `En` which lets you change the language

Comment: I have no bar at the top of the screen. This shows up only when I boot up and goes to my user log in screen, however it changes every time I reboot